# How use the @c8y/client library

Tags: cumulocity

I am testing the new @c8y/client library for typescript.

I have a very simple code :

```
import {
  Client
} from '@c8y/client';
//const baseUrl = 'https://bismark1.cumulocity.com/';
const baseUrl = 'https://demos.cumulocity.com/';
const tenant = 'bismark1';
const user = '...';
const password = '.....';


(async() => {
  console.log('authentication to c8y server')
  const client = await Client.authenticate({
    user,
    password,
    tenant
  }, baseUrl);

  console.log('result from authetication', client)
  const {
    data,
    paging
  } = await client.inventory.list();
  console.log('result from inventory ', data)

  // data = first page of inventory
  const nextPage = await paging.next();
  // nextPage.data = second page of inventory

  const managedObjId: number = 1;

  (async() => {
    const {
      data,
      res
    } = await client.inventory.detail(managedObjId);
    console.log(data)
  })();

})();
```

When I run the .js compiled form the .ts file  I get the response below :

```
authentication to c8y server
```

And then the execution stops.

The line

```
console.log('result from authetication', client)
```

is never called. Seems like something fails in the authentication process and not error is showed.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem might be [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You need to enable it if you want to request from a different domain. [Here is a guide](http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/administration/#-a-name-default-app-a-changing-application-settings) how to do that in Cumulocity:

> Under "Access control", administrators can enable cross-origin
>   resource sharing or "CORS" on the Cumulocity API.

The second problem could be that you are **not** running it from a local development server. I mostly use this [http-server from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to quickly test scripts. You can use it the following way:

```
$ npm install http-server -g
$ http-server
```

---

If that all is not helping you might try catch the client to see the error it is throwing:

```
try {
  const client = await Client.authenticate({
    user,
    password,
    tenant
  }, baseUrl);
} catch(ex) {
 console.log(ex);
}
```

The exeption might tell you more about what is wrong with your code or if there is a bug in the client.

Comment: I have same problem, and I have enabled Access Control and have local webpack dev server. Still I get cors warning / issue.

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://cumulocityplatformURL/tenant/currentTenant' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field pragma is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I see Pragma in request headers and its not allowed in the backend, so is this webpack dev server issue or Angular issue?

Comment: this is a bug @c8y/client and was fixed in 9.19.0. Can you update the client to that version `npm install @c8y/client@9.19.0` and check again?

Comment: Yes that did it! Thanks a lot for quick reply. I'm amazed.

Comment: do you know how can I store c8y/client login info to be used in another components? Should I store login info to localstorage or how can I use logged client in elsewhere? The documentation is bit plain.

Comment: Yep, local storage would work. Cumulocity itself uses angular service to store the information at application runtime and for permanent local or session storage.